# How to change Crystal Report data source from Jet DB tables to CSV flat files?

Tags: crystal-reports

We currently have several Crystal Reports (CR) 8.5 report templates that we want to change the data source from Jet DB tables to CSV flat files. This is part of our project to get our applications using the modern CR 13 run-time. The problem we are having is, when we use the Visual Studio 2010 IDE to change the data source for the reports from the Jet DB tables to our new CSV flat files, the DB fields that are embedded in the report template are being deleted.

We want to point at the new type of data source (CSV flat files) in our report templates without losing the existing embedded data fields in the reports. In other words, we to use the CR IDE to re-map the current DB data fields to the new fields in the CSV files. We really want to avoid having to re-embed then reformat the data fields after pointing the report at the flat files.

So far we have not found a way to do this. Our Google searches have come up empty on this subject. Any help you can offer is appreciated.